# You would think he would help me

Tags: modal-verbs

Q) If someone **didn't help you (on a particular occasion)/has never helped you in the past**, can you say any one of the following:

a) You would think he would help me. (implying he didn't help/has never helped me in the past)

b) You would think he would have helped me. (same as above)

c) You would have thought he would help me. (same as above)

d) You would have thought he would have helped me. (same as above)

Comment: They're all acceptable and equivalent. But #4 in particular is a bit of a mouthful, so some people might want to avoid that one. In any case, almost all native speakers would probably contract at least one if not both instances of ***would*** there to ***'d***. Note that the "non-perfect subordinate clause" versions (a and c) could ***also*** be used if *it's not yet known whether he **will** help*. But b and d ***always*** imply ***he didn't help***.

Comment: Thank you. You say,  *the "non-perfect subordinate clause" versions (a and c) could also be used if it's not yet known whether he will help*--- Do you mean that in (a) and (c) the speaker *expects* him to help the speaker in the future?

Comment: As I said, versions #a and #c can be used to refer to some ***future*** situation (so we can't yet know if he ***will*** help). But as regards whether speaker ***expects*** that future help to be forthcoming - it's all a matter of ***context***. The exact same words (even, ***spoken in the same way***, I believe) could either mean *We can't be sure, but **he'll probably help**,* OR *If you think he'll help me, **you're almost certainly mistaken***.

Comment: Bear in mind that if someone starts a "conversation" by telling the other person what they (the other person) think (or *might* think), fairly obviously there's something at least a *little* "strange" going on. Just as there's something a bit odd about saying what you yourself ***would*** think (why not just say what you ***do*** think?). A lot of "conversations" that include such factors are actually ***intended*** to be vague or misleading.